# Syntax formatting for SQL Insert into statements in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb

I am attempting to insert a Date, Time, and Temperature value from sensors I have installed in the field. I have all the computations and variables working as intended but the sql statement fails. Here is the a rough format of how the argument is formatted:

```
  arg=('2019-07-21', '07:00:00', 29.323330729166656)
```

My SQL table is formatted as follows:

Date (as DATE), Time (as TIME), Temperature (as DOUBLE)

However, the insert into statement fails due to the standard 1064 error in MariaDB. " (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00,29.323330729166656)' at line 1")"

Here is the SQL statement:

```
for row in arg:
        print(row)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO flirtest (Date, Time, Temperature) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" % row)
db.commit()
```

I think this error is due to the quotes around the first two variables. But I am honestly not sure. How should these statements be properly formatted in python? Should quotes be included or not?

Comment: Do you need a trailing comma in that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
  in your case, arg is a Tuple, so it goes thorugh 3 times: in the first round, row is '2019-07-21', in the secound round row is '07:00:00', you get it.

Just put "[ ]" around it to set it to a list, then there is only 1 round with everything :)

2.
  Yours should then work too, but try this:

```
arg=[('2019-07-21', '07:00:00', 29.323330729166656)]

for row in arg:
        print(row)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO flirtest (Date, Time, Temperature) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", row)
db.commit()
```

But im not 100% sure, because I use mysql :)

Comment: Thank you! The extra brackets was the fix!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but I think this will be closer:

```
arg=('2019-07-21', '07:00:00', 29.323330729166656,)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO flirtest (Date, Time, Temperature) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", %row)
db.commit()
```